# Receive Server Error 500 on Heroku with Django for specific pages with images (static served by WhiteNoise)

Tags: django, heroku, static, django-staticfiles, whitenoise

For the last couple of hours I've been searching through Stack Overflow for a fix, but most posts about the Server Error 500 could not provide a fix for me. Django can't find static images and returns a 500. The images are in static/css/images.

for example, I try to get https://monkeyparliament.herokuapp.com/about/. Logs return:

```
2019-02-10T17:09:33.362724+00:00 app[web.1]: ValueError: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'css\images\donate.png'
2019-02-10T17:09:33.363611+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.31.121.50 - - [10/Feb/2019:17:09:33 +0000] "GET /about/ HTTP/1.1" 500 27 "https://monkeyparliament.herokuapp.com/music/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.96 Safari/537.36"
```

But when I https://monkeyparliament.herokuapp.com/music/, it seems it can find css/js/fonts in the static folder. Feel free to inspect the page source.

My static images are served by WhiteNoise (http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/). As you can see above, WhiteNoise is in the requirements. MIDDLEWARE in settings.py has 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware' added below django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware'.

Why are my images not found?

**Procfile**

```
web: gunicorn websitemp.wsgi:application --log-file -
```

**Requirements.txt**

```
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==2.0.10
gunicorn==19.9.0
psycopg2==2.7.7
pytz==2018.9
whitenoise==4.1.2
```

**Structure**

website is the app, websitemp is the project

[image]

**Project on Github**

if you want to see the full structure you can find all files on the github: https://github.com/DennisVerstappen/websitempdjango

Thanks in advance!

Comment: does that donate.png is available, check in your template.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. donate.png is placed in static/css/images. The template has this reference to donate.png:            <img src="{% static 'css\images\donate.png' %}" alt="donate" class="donateIcon"/>

Comment: I have gone through your github. Have you run collect static and your app is finding the image in local system? Or I have a better solution. Remove `STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)` from your settings and add static folder inside your app `website` instead of adding it in the project folder. And now you can add `{% static 'css/images/donate.png' %}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for thinking along. After trying your solutions I noticed that the slashes in

```
{% static 'css\images\donate.png' %}
```

differed from the slashed in other Python files in the logs. Changing the  backslashes to forwardslashes fixed my problem. The folder system notation that I used (Windows) differed from the one Heroku uses. Using the notation below worked.

```
{% static 'css/images/donate.png' %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a empty folder **staticfiles** in your main directory.

Afterwards run `python manage.py collectstatic`

After that it should be filled with all static assets from all applications.

Note: To keep things seperated you can actually, move your **static** folder into the **Website-Application** - Should not make a difference